# Update from kubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS failed

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kubuntu

I am running a dual boot Windows XP and Kubuntu 14.04 LTS on an old Acer Aspire One netbook. 
I hadn't used it in a long time but when I recently did, I was given the option of updating to Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I chose to update.

This took several hours and a few error messages appeared telling me that something had failed to install properly.
Just before the update was complete a message came up which said that there were too many errors and the update had failed but my computer would reboot and try to save the system.

It did not automatically reboot and would only switch off by holding down the power button.
When I switched it back on, a black screen with 'Kubuntu 16.04' shows up and loads for a bit to the login screen but here the mouse is completely frozen and as the cursor is not in the login box I am unsure whether the keyboard is also frozen.

The only thing I am able to do is switch it off by holding down the power button. Windows XP still works fine from the boot menu.
Is there any way I can fix this so I can run Kubuntu again (I don't mind downgrading to the previous LTS (14.04) or even changing to Xubuntu)?

Comment: It seems that your update broke. I would follow Votlon's answer by trying to use a LiveCD to save your data, and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bricked situation, You have two options:

Boot over with a live cd and try to mount the linux system to restore data if you did not back up before upgrading. Then reinstall the system with a new 16.04 iso.

Or screw the data, just reinstall the system with a new iso. :)
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release/